# Is it possible to use Entity Framework with Windows Azure development storage service?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, azure, azure-sql-database

EDIT:
Is it possible to use Entity Framework with Windows Azure development storage service? and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be possible or practical. Azure Storage (different from SQL Azure) doesn't support joining and may not respond well to ad-hoc queries. But you don't need it. [Azure storage already supports LINQ and object mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894039.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Craig's answer is right for Windows Azure storage.  For SQL Azure, there's no such thing as development storage, but you can use EF against SQL Azure in the cloud, and you can use EF against SQL Server locally.

Comment: True, the question is confusingly worded, and it's not clear which of these two very different services he's using. Of course, he didn't name them, MS did, so credit for the confusion where it's due...

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's my mistake. I've already fixed my post. Thanks.