# Is there an Entity Framework data provider for the Azure Blob Service?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, azure-blob-storage

I'm considering using WCF Data Services to implement a service exposing objects stored in the Azure Blob Service. I wonder if I could use a data model based on the Entity Framework. As I understand, I would need a data provider compatible with the Entity Framework that could store and retrieve data from the Blob service. Is there such a data provider?

Comment: Did you ever hear anything about this ?

Comment: I don't think there is any ready-made solution for this. On a second thought, EF is probably not a good match for Azure Storage anyway. I created an answer with what I could find out about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a data provider for Azure Storage that is compatible with Entity Framework. Creating such a data provider is probably not worthwhile because it's a very complex project and because Entity Framework is not a good match for Azure Storage's conceptual model. Entity Framework is designed for relational databases and Azure Storage is REST-based non-relational storage.

As for creating a WCF Data Services layer over Azure Storage, it could be built using [WCF Data Services Toolkit](http://wcfdstoolkit.codeplex.com/).

References:

- [Is it possible to use Entity Framework with Windows Azure development storage service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156203/is-it-possible-to-use-entity-framework-with-windows-azure-development-storage-se)
- [Entity Framework with Azure Storage Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837696/is-there-an-entity-framework-data-provider-for-the-azure-blob-service)
- [Access Azure table storage via WCF Data Services (CSAzureTableStorageWCFDS)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/CSAzureTableStorageWCFDS-2355159b)